# If $f$ is holomorphic on a region $\Omega$ is $\Omega$ connected?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading a proof which tries to show that $f$ is constant if $f' = 0$ on a region $\Omega$ where $f$ is holomorphic. The proof begins by trying to show that there exists a $w_0$ such that $f(w) = f(w_0)$ for all $w \in \Omega.$ It then seems to assume that since $\Omega$ is connected there is a curve $\gamma$ that connects $w_0$ to $w$ for any $w.$ First of all, how can they assume $\Omega$ is connected? I assume it has something to do with the fact that $f$ is holomorphic?

Comment: No, $\Omega$ being connected is probably an implicit assumption throughout the chapter. Go back to the beginning of the relevant section of the book and you should find this assumption explicitly stated.

Comment: Generally complex analysis books define a domain as a connected open set, then work only on domains. It should be mentioned somewhere, though.

Comment: A region is usually defined to be an *open and connected* subset of the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

They must be assuming $\Omega$ is connected.

After all, suppose $\Omega = U_1\cup U_2$ is the union of two connected, disjoint components. If $f$ is holomorphic on $U_1$ and $g$ is holomorphic on $U_2$, the function $h$ defined to be $f$ on $U_1$ and $g$ on $U_2$ surely satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations